# Upgrading an old dusty 20.04 installation on a new motherboard, ethernet not working

Tags: apt, upgrade, chroot

I have an old 20.04.1 Ubuntu installation that wasn't touched since 2020, that I need to boot on to revive an old development project that was let unfinished. The motherboard & CPU changed and are not compatible with Legacy boot, but I could finally install an UEFI grub with a Live CD and boot successfully.

Now as expected the Intel 12th gen chipset isn't supported and I have no network connection. Fortunately booting on a 20.04.6 live CD shows it is now supported, and I just need to apt upgrade Ubuntu... without network.

Would booting on the Live CD, mounting the Ubuntu partition and chrooting into it be a viable solution for apt upgrade? Or is it a bad idea, are there other clean ways?

Comment: Booting to the Live CD, and chrooting the installation to the hard drive, is the most appropriate solution.